# ReactNative : redux-form validating inputs immediately

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to use `redux-form` with `react-native`. I tried to do something what I did when I used `redux-form`s for web apps. I am trying to validate the form using `redux-form`, but I am immediately seeing validations instead of it triggering `onBlur` or when focus changes.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';


const renderTextInput = ({
  input: { onChange, ...restInput }, // eslint-disable-line
  placeholder, // eslint-disable-line
  autoCapitalize, // eslint-disable-line
  maxLength, // eslint-disable-line
  isPassword, // eslint-disable-line
  isEmail, // eslint-disable-line
  meta: { touched, error, warning }, // eslint-disable-line
}) => (
  <View style={{ width: '100%', paddingBottom: 15 }}>
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={onChange}
      style={[styles.textInput, { width: '100%' }]}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      maxLength={maxLength}
      secureTextEntry={isPassword || false}
      keyboardType={isEmail ? 'email-address' : 'default'}
      {...restInput}
    />
    {error && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</Text>}
  </View>
);

class SignUp extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  onFormSubmit = (values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
      >
        <Field
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email Address"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          isEmail
          maxLength={50}
          component={renderTextInput}
        />
        <Field
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          maxLength={50}
          isPassword
          autoCapitalize="none"
          component={renderTextInput}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)}
          underlayColor="transparent"
          style={{ height: 40, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#005abc' }}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18 }}>
              Sign Up!
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // styles
});
// Why is this triggering immediately as the screen loads ?
const validate = (values) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.email) errors.firstName = 'Email is required...';
  return errors;
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signUpForm',
  validate,
})(SignUp);
```

Packages:

```
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.3",
"react-native-navigation": "^1.1.236",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-form": "^7.1.1",
```

Note: The alert in the image below is when app is loaded first time and in the background you can see the validation error being shown.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have a form that wraps all of your fields with an onSubmit attribute?

Comment: Also, I'd check out the new syntax for exporting a form with the newer versions of Redux Form. About half way down the page you can see an example of the correct way to export now. Not sure if yours is correct, but I know it has changed since prior versions, and messes things up sometimes. https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/docs/gettingstarted.md/

Comment: @DanielZuzevich: Thank you for your input. I solved it. What I had to do was use the `touched` property while showing the error. This will trigger the error only when the input is touched.

```{{touched && error && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</Text>}```

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear you got it fixed. This post at least motivated me to read some of the Redux form docs. I don't use it personally, but might now.

Comment: `redux-form`s are really cool. I have used them before for web application, used them for first time for a native app. I completely missed the `touched` property! Got the answer from my own repo https://github.com/ghoshabhi/simple-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/app/client/src/components/NewPost.jsx#L11

Comment: Very nice. Will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the `touched` property of the `meta` object. My final function to render input looks like this:

```
const renderTextInput = ({
  ...,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }, // added 'touched' here
}) => (
  <View style={{ width: '100%', paddingBottom: 15 }}>
    <TextInput
      ...
    />
    {touched && error && <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{error}</Text>}
  </View>
);
```